# GitlabHQ - DB - How are the commit graphs made and which table is this information stored?

Tags: gitlab

I am able to access the Gitlab db through console. However, I am unable to find any relation between users and commits in the gitlabhq schema. Can anyone tell me, which fields and tables correspond to this particular relation?

Reference: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/db/schema.rb

Answer (score 0):

The recent stable development build of the git repo was much helpful here.
The relation is such that, every activity that the user does(commit, MergeRequest, Issue) is tracked in the table named as 'notes' under the field - noteable_type. This is mapped to the user based on the author_id; i.e.) author_id <==> user_id.